# How can I prevent a world from getting too large without installing plug-ins?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was hoping to have a pure vanilla server, but the size of the world is causing huge memory usage when only a few players are on the server. Is there a way I can prevent users from exploring so far in the vanilla version of Minecraft?

Comment: Sorry, crm.  We don't do recommendations.  If you tell us what problem you're attempting to solve, instead of the solution you want, we might be able to help you with that.

Comment: @fbueckert This might be right on the line, he's stating a problem with memory usages and asking for a mod that might fix it. It might be barely walking the line, what do you think?

Comment: @Linuxmint Nope.  This is over the line.  He's attempting to solve the problem by adding a world border.  If the question was focused on, "My world is causing huge memory usage, how can I fix that?", that would be a problem we could help with.  An assumption is being made as to how the problem should be solved.

Comment: I'm confused how "the size of the world is causing huge memory usage when only a few players are on the server" is not a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: "Mods, config files, maps, ini files, controller layouts, etc are all solutions to problems. They don't automatically make a question good or bad for being mentioned in it, or for being the only way to solve a given question. Similarly, their mention doesn't make a bad question good. Disconnect the two, and look past the word choices and presupposed answers." - http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-an-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing/6830#6830

Comment: @JasonBerkan So edit out the automatic assumption asking for a mod.

Comment: @fbueckert We *do* do mod recs if they're asking for a solution to a problem. *Please* stop trying to close all the Minecraft questions which may ask for a mod! You're helping nobody.

Comment: @dlras2 This has been edited to remove the mod assumption.  Now it's no longer a mod recommendation question.  THOSE are what I object to, regardless of whether they're for Minecraft or not.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a mod, but it will help with your issue.

I have used this method on my server, and it helped cut down on *A LOT* of lag.

1. Download MCEdit, a world-editing tool, from their website (http://www.mcedit.net).
2. Inside of MCEdit, chose which world you would like to create the border on.
3. Make walls around the area you wish to have players kept in, using the invisible Block 36.

This method above will keep everyone within the walls of Block 36, allowing no new chunks to form, so your game runs faster!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also you can use it to just delete blocks outside the border. To allowing only the blocks in side the area to be loaded.

Answer (score 6):

Not to my knowledge. The only mods that are still up to date with Minecraft are Bukkit plugins only.

Also, while it is possible for large worlds to cause memory usage issues, it's not the most common of issues. I'm sure you've already done your research, but you may want to verify that it is in-fact, a world size issue.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, and you can do it without any mods or external editors, and without generating all of the terrain you want to section off.

You can do this by setting up a simple [redstone clock circuit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock_circuit) connected to one or more [command blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block). If, for example, you wanted to limit players to within 2500 blocks of 0,0, you could then use the [player selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Arguments) `@a[x=0,y=64,z=0,rm=2500]` to select all players "out-of-bounds". Just make sure that this setup is encased in bedrock or inaccessible from non-op players.

Using this, you could do things like tell them to turn around using `/tell`, teleport them back to spawn using `/tp` or `/kill` them outright, or anything else you want such as progressively [slowing them down with `/effect`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion_Effects#List_of_effects) as they wander off.

Comment: Nice idea! That's great for use with only command blocks!

Answer (score 1):

As anyone hasn't said anything about the reasons behind exploring, I thought I could share some experience (although this might be dated).

Maps more often than not concentrate a very large *featureless* biome (desert or tundra) on the start point. As Minecraft concentrates certain resources (such as sugar cane, or snow, or even wood) on certain biomes, the key to having a *good* map would be to get a seed that somehow concentrates any desirable feature around 640 to 1152 blocks of the center point (as all strongholds are located at random positions in that radius).

Then, as suggested by @Tech, you can wall off the exterior sections. I must tell you that it is impossible to completely cut off a section of a map.

Minecraft was made to be an *endless* experience. Walling the "real world" doesn't wall off the Nether. Assuming you could wall off the Nether, people could, with some effort, climb the walls. I have sporadically used some mods but they failed more often than they should.

The best course of action, all considered, is to ask gently not to explore much. And the best way to prevent that is by limiting the urge to explore.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I bought a $10 a month hosting plan from DigitalOcean, and needed it to not use up the 1 gig of memory I had, as I needed to run some other servers.

Simply use world border! If you have a 1.8 server, you can use /worldborder set *number of blocks* to set the maximum number of blocks players can go from the world spawn point. You can set that too with /setworldspawn. You can read more about these commands at https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#worldborder and https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setworldspawn

You can also disable the Nether in server.properties if you wish!